# Using "python --version" command bringing up error message

Tags: python, pandas, shell, version

I have Python 3.7.1 on my Windows 10 PC. I want to install Pandas and firstly need to do some checks to see if I have everything required. I tried typing the following to double check the Python version:

```
python --version
```

but it keeps spitting out the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

According to the Pandas website, if this error occurs it's because I need to type it into Python Shell. But that's what I'm doing... I know I'm probably missing something really obvious, but I'd really appreciate any hints and tips for this very basic problem...

Thanks!

Comment: `python --version` this must be entered in your `cmd` not inside python `REPL`.

Comment: I guess your python installation is broken, try to remove it completely and reinstall.

Comment: You misunderstand the instructions.  “python” is the name of the python interpreter, it is not a python command.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be entering `python --version` in a Python shell. Enter it in the cmd.exe shell.

Answer (score 1):

You probably get this Error:

[image]

The answer from RasikhJ is right, except you have to use brackets in your Python3 version:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

If you just want to know your Python version, then use the command line:

1. Search for cmd or command line on your Windows
2. Change your folder to the "python.exe" file (something like C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32) with the "cd" command
3. Now you can type in "python --version" and you get your Version

[image]

Comment: If you need more information how to install Pandas, feel free to ask :). But actually you just have to go to your command line and move to your pip folder, something like "cd C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Scripts". Then you can use "pip install pandas" or any other package you want to install.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sys package:

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

Or use the platform module:

```
import platform
print platform.python_version()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `py --version` in `cmd`.

```
C:\Users\XYZ>py --version
Python 3.8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `py --version` in cmd.

```
C:\Users\XYZ>py --version
Python 3.8.3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see python version in python prompt 
import sys 
print(sys.version)
[image: you will get this result]

The command which you are trying  meant for cmd/terminal prompt. Also your python environment should be set to get below results 
[image]